# JQuery AJAX in Master Page using asmx in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am calling webservice for checkin Login in master page using jquery Ajax.
JavaScript:

```
function Login() {
    var UserName = $("[id*=tbUserName]").val();
    var PassWord = $("[id*=tbPassword]").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/WebServiceLogin.asmx/LoginUser") %>',
        data: "{'username':'" + UserName + "','password':'" + PassWord + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var j = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d);
            if (j["msg"] == "success")
                window.location = 'UserDashHome.aspx';
            else {
               window.location = 'Login.aspx';
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("error:" + response.data + response.d);
        }
    });
}
```

ASMX Code:

```
[ScriptMethod]
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]    
    public string LoginUser(String username,String password)
    {
        try
        {
            MobileStoreEntities mse = new MobileStoreEntities();
            UserMast um = new UserMast();

            if (mse.UserMasts.Where(user => user.Email == username && user.Password == password).Count() > 0)
            {
                if (mse.UserMasts.Where(user => user.Email == username && user.Password == password && user.Status==true).Count() > 0)
                {
                    EncryptDecrypt ed=new EncryptDecrypt();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginUserName"] = ed.Encrypt(username);
                    var userObj = mse.UserMasts.First(a => a.Email == username);
                    int id = userObj.UserID;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginID"] = ed.Encrypt(id.ToString());    

                    return "{\"msg\":\"success\"}";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "{\"msg\":\"Please make sure you make complete varification process if yes then contact admin.!\"}";
                }
            }

            if (mse.UserMasts.Where(user => user.UserName == username && user.Password == password).Count() > 0)
            {
                if (mse.UserMasts.Where(user => user.UserName == username && user.Password == password && user.Status==true).Count() > 0)
                {
                    EncryptDecrypt ed = new EncryptDecrypt();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginUserName"] = ed.Encrypt(username);
                    var userObj = mse.UserMasts.First(a => a.UserName == username);
                    int id = userObj.UserID;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginID"] = ed.Encrypt(id.ToString());  
                    return "{\"msg\":\"success\"}";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "{\"msg\":\"Please make sure you complete varification process if yes then contact admin.!\"}";
                }
            }
            return "{\"msg\":\"Wrong username or password.!\"}";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "{\"msg\":'" + e.Message + "'}";
        }
    }
```

I am Getting Error Undefined..
One More thing..My webservice.asmx file is in root folder and webservice.cs file in APP_CODE..Is it because of that?

Comment: Is the error in your browser console?

Comment: ...and is your jquery embedded on the page or linked from another file?

Comment: Are your username and password fields being picked up correctly? Can you separate your selects from the variable assignment?

Comment: @bukko-I have used External JQuery...

Comment: I mean your script. I assume it is embedded (otherwise `<$= =>` won't work)

Comment: Yes...it is embedded..if i put alert in script..it is showing message..

Comment: If you split your username/password select and assignments you'll be able to work out if that is the problem, e.g.: `var $username=$("[id*=tbUserName]"); var UserName=$username.val();` - but on separate lines for debugging

Comment: I think error is just because of URL not getting path of asmx file..because same code works if i use it in aspx not in master page

Comment: Need more detail. What line is the error on? Have you used an `alert` to prove the URL is defined correctly? (same for the other assignments)

Comment: If you are using an external .js file to write the AJAX call then this line would not work and might be causing the issue: url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/WebServiceLogin.asmx/LoginUser") %>',

Comment: it might be that...but I Don't know how to solve it...

Comment: Change your alert in error function like this to see what is the error alert("error:" + response);

Comment: its showing me...object [object]..nothing else

Comment: OK Change it to this alert("error:" + JSON.stringify(response));

Comment: it is showing me invalid URL..Bad Request

Comment: I have change my URL to this:
 url: '/WebServiceLogin.asmx/LoginUser',

Comment: Thank You guys now its working well...there were two issue..one related to path and another is uncomment Script Service..Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Change your script as follows:

```
function Login() {
    var UserName = $("[id*=tbUserName]").val();
    var PassWord = $("[id*=tbPassword]").val();
    var wsUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/WebServiceLogin.asmx/LoginUser") %>';
    alert(wsUrl);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: wsUrl,
        data: "{'username':'" + UserName + "','password':'" + PassWord + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var j = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d);
            if (j["msg"] == "success")
                window.location = 'UserDashHome.aspx';
            else {
               window.location = 'Login.aspx';
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("error:" + response.data + response.d);
        }
    });
}
```

This will show you if your Url is correct.

As I said in the comment, it will be blank if your script is not embedded directly in the page.